# How to handle space in file name in Marklogic?

Tags: document, marklogic

If the file name or directory name has a space in it. How to handle it in Marklogic?

While loading it through [`xdmp:document-load`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:document-load) it throws an error.
And in case of MLCP it replaces the space with %.

Answer (score 1):

[fn:escape-uri()](https://docs.marklogic.com/fn:escape-uri) may be what you want.

I suggest that the second parameter be set to false. That way slashes will still show up as slashes (important for some uses within MarkLogic).